# Concurrent UPDATE statements of single row in small table takes minutes

Tags: postgresql, locking, postgresql-performance, blocking

I have a very simple table with no indexes (although scan_uuid *could* have a UNIQUE index if that helps):

```
create table public.host_scan_complete_log_counts
(
    scan_uuid uuid not null,
    num_shards_completed numeric default 0 not null
);
```

I then have a few hundred nodes each with their own direct connection to the database. As they work, they perform an update on this table like so:

```
UPDATE host_scan_complete_log_counts 
SET num_shards_completed = num_shards_completed + $2
WHERE scan_uuid = $1
```

Although there is never a deadlock, these UPDATE statements can take several *minutes* to complete.

Since the table of scan counts is so small, I expected the UPDATE statements to take very small fractions of a second and therefore no queue of UPDATEs to build up. But it seems that isn't the case, possibly due to some locking clashes. Is there some way to improve this situation perhaps with more sophisticated UPDATE SQL?

Here's the output of a query showing the age of the locks that get generated, in case that is useful.

```
SELECT   l.relation::regclass,
         l.transactionid,
         l.mode,
         l.GRANTED,
         a.query,
         a.query_start,
         age(now(), a.query_start) AS "age",
         a.pid
FROM pg_stat_activity a
JOIN pg_locks l ON l.pid = a.pid
ORDER BY a.query_start;
```

| relation | transactionid | mode | granted | query | query_start | age | pid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | ExclusiveLock | t | UPDATE host_scan_complete_log_counts SET num_shards_completed = num_shards_completed + $2 WHERE scan_uuid = $1 | 2021-01-31 22:17:20.921768+00 | 00:02:24.465192 | 15624 |
|  | 6826571 | ExclusiveLock | t | UPDATE host_scan_complete_log_counts SET num_shards_completed = num_shards_completed + $2 WHERE scan_uuid = $1 | 2021-01-31 22:17:20.921768+00 | 00:02:24.465192 | 15624 |
| host_scan_complete_log_counts |  | ExclusiveLock | f | UPDATE host_scan_complete_log_counts SET num_shards_completed = num_shards_completed + $2 WHERE scan_uuid = $1 | 2021-01-31 22:17:20.921768+00 | 00:02:24.465192 | 15624 |
| host_scan_complete_log_counts |  | RowExclusiveLock | t | UPDATE host_scan_complete_log_counts SET num_shards_completed = num_shards_completed + $2 WHERE scan_uuid = $1 | 2021-01-31 22:17:20.921768+00 | 00:02:24.465192 | 15624 |
| host_scan_complete_log_counts |  | ExclusiveLock | f | UPDATE host_scan_complete_log_counts SET num_shards_completed = num_shards_completed + $2 WHERE scan_uuid = $1 | 2021-01-31 22:18:03.688236+00 | 00:01:41.698724 | 22147 |
|  | 6826937 | ExclusiveLock | t | UPDATE host_scan_complete_log_counts SET num_shards_completed = num_shards_completed + $2 WHERE scan_uuid = $1 | 2021-01-31 22:18:03.688236+00 | 00:01:41.698724 | 22147 |
| host_scan_complete_log_counts |  | RowExclusiveLock | t | UPDATE host_scan_complete_log_counts SET num_shards_completed = num_shards_completed + $2 WHERE scan_uuid = $1 | 2021-01-31 22:18:03.688236+00 | 00:01:41.698724 | 22147 |
|  |  | ExclusiveLock | t | UPDATE host_scan_complete_log_counts SET num_shards_completed = num_shards_completed + $2 WHERE scan_uuid = $1 | 2021-01-31 22:18:03.688236+00 | 00:01:41.698724 | 22147 |
|  | 6827769 | ShareLock | f | UPDATE host_scan_complete_log_counts SET num_shards_completed = num_shards_completed + $2 WHERE scan_uuid = $1 | 2021-01-31 22:18:12.969814+00 | 00:01:32.417146 | 22179 |
| host_scan_complete_log_counts |  | RowExclusiveLock | t | UPDATE host_scan_complete_log_counts SET num_shards_completed = num_shards_completed + $2 WHERE scan_uuid = $1 | 2021-01-31 22:18:12.969814+00 | 00:01:32.417146 | 22179 |
|  |  | ExclusiveLock | t | UPDATE host_scan_complete_log_counts SET num_shards_completed = num_shards_completed + $2 WHERE scan_uuid = $1 | 2021-01-31 22:18:12.969814+00 | 00:01:32.417146 | 22179 |
|  | 6827071 | ExclusiveLock | t | UPDATE host_scan_complete_log_counts SET num_shards_completed = num_shards_completed + $2 WHERE scan_uuid = $1 | 2021-01-31 22:18:12.969814+00 | 00:01:32.417146 | 22179 |

Comment: Are you making an explicit transaction and not closing? Do you have `AUTOCOMMIT` on or off?

Comment: The ExclusiveLock on host_scan_complete_log_counts seems like the culprit. But the UPDATE statement wouldn't take that lock. And it can't be an earlier statement in the same transaction, as that lock is not being held, but being blocked on. Do you have an update trigger which tries to refresh a materialized view concurrently, or which does explicit table locking?

Comment: @jjanes I haven't created an update triggers and I don't have any explicit locking. My queries are executed with asyncpg.execute so I'm not even using any fancy ORM. I did read somewhere that Postgres can automatically fallback to acquiring higher level locks when lower level locks fail, which could maybe be happening due to the number of concurrent workers fighting to update the same row?

Comment: @Charlieface AUTOCOMMIT is enabled and there is no explicit transaction, the UPDATE SQL is simply run with Python's `asyncpg.execute()`.

Comment: Can several nodes hit the same scan_uuid? Does making scan_uuid the primary key help?

Comment: Yes @bobflux, almost all the nodes will be trying to increment the same `scan_uuid`. I can try making it the primary key for the table - curious how it might help?

Comment: Ouch. And... just a hunch. How many updates per second does that row get? (per node and total, approximation is fine, no need to get really exact). Also check pg_relation_size() so we know if the table is bloated maybe.

Comment: Also you have a few hundred nodes with a postgres connection each? So, hundreds of postgres processes? No connection pool? Check the cpu load on server, memory utilization, output of "vmstat 1" to check iowait and swap, etc

Comment: "ps aux |grep -c postgres" gives number of postgres processes, you can add all that stuff to the question

Comment: hey @bobflux, I'm planning on addressing this by serializing all the updates from the nodes instead of trying to do them simultaneously. But to answer your Qs: each node attempts to update that row once every 2 minutes and there are 320 nodes. Each node has 1 connection to the DB. The load on the DB was moderate.

Comment: If all the nodes trying to update at exactly the same wall clock time, you could spread them out, add random time offset between 0 and 2 mins at the beginning of the program and then update every 2 mins... but it would be simpler to serialize as you say, have the nodes INSERT the updates they want to do in a table, and a single process just grabs that and update the contentious row